# SQL - Determine if Column in Group are all the same value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a SQL table that is grouped by serial numbers, with a secondary data column. Per serial number, I'd like to count if the data column has all equivalent values of a specific values For example

| Serial# | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | pass |
| 1 | pass |
| 2 | pass |
| 2 | fail |
| 3 | fail |
| 3 | fail |
| 3 | fail |

I'd have a count of "1" for serial#1, but 2 and 3 would be "0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "sum" to obtain the success:

```sql
SELECT 
    [Serial#], 
    1 + Sgn(-Abs(Sum([Data] <> 'pass'))) AS Success
FROM 
    SerialTable
GROUP BY 
    [Serial#];
```

or, using `Min` as suggested by *Mat*:

```sql
SELECT [Serial#], Min(Abs([Data] = 'pass')) AS Success
FROM SerialTable
GROUP BY [Serial#];
```

Comment: Just use min? Something like `MIN(IIF([Data] = 'pass', 1, 0))`?

Comment: @MatBailie: Yes, indeed. I've added that, again using `Abs`. Thanks!

Comment: Neither of these two queries seem to do what user2059972 is asking for. If you expand the record set by adding another 'Pass' record for serial 1 you do not get a count and they both return exactly the same result (=1) as if that record was not there. Worse yet, if you add a 'Pass' record for serial 2, they still return zero for that serial. The point is, they both return the correct result but only when based on the exact data provided by user2059972. When the data is changed, the results are incorrect. My answer below will handle this scenario.

Comment: @BobS: They both will work, also for your extended data examples. Criteria is that a _Serial#_ must have "pass" _Data_ entries only to have "1" returned, otherwise "0" shall be returned. That makes sense to me.

Comment: @Gustav, not trying to be argumentative here but you are only grouping on Serial. The Data portion will be random by record and from what my test shows, it seems that the SQL engine is only looking at the _first_ Data record it reads when performing the grouping on Serial, so if that happens to be a Fail with two subsequent Passes, you will get zero which is incorrect. And whether the value is a count or zero is irrelevant to the logic. The count will be either zero or non-zero.

Comment: @BobS: I did try to add records as you mention, but my query still returns the correct result. Also, there is no counting, only if a "fail" exists or not. The questioneer my enlighten us.

Comment: @Gustav: I am totally perplexed. Try as I might I have been unable to get either query to produce the correct result either in Access 2010 or Access 2016. If you like, is it possible to take this discussion offline or into another area? I do not want to clutter up this post any further.

Comment: We could, but I don't think we will get closer until the questioneer provides some feedback, indeed how to interpret _I'd have a count of "1" for serial#1, but 2 and 3 would be "0"_, which I believe should read: _I'd have a result of "1" for serial#1, but 2 and 3 would be "0"_

Comment: Agreed. My main motivation is to try and find out why I am apparently getting a different result than you.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are not interested in multiple Fail values so this SQL should do what you want. Just replace `YourTable` with your own table name:

```
SELECT YourTable.Serial, 
Nz(
(SELECT TOP 1 Count([T1].[Serial] & [T1].[Data]) AS SerDataCount 
FROM YourTable AS T1 
WHERE T1.Serial=[YourTable].[Serial] AND T1.Data='Pass' 
GROUP BY T1.Serial, T1.Data;)-1,0
) AS SerCount

FROM YourTable
GROUP BY YourTable.Serial;
```